# IS it possible to use the 'Where' clause in SQL to only show a field containing only letters & Numbers?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, select, where-clause

I want to be able to select only the field where a certain field contains both letters and numbers. for example:

```
Select [field1], [field2] 

from [db1].[table1] 

where [field2] = *LETTERS AND NUMBERS*
```

Im using SQL Server 2005, also im sorry bu im not a hundred percent sure about the data type of the field because it is on a linked server and un-accessibleat the minute. Hope you can help

:)

Comment: I don't think tsql supports regular expressions, which would have been my first answer.

Comment: This question has `regex` written all over it. Not an area of strength in SQL-server, maybe this can help you: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163473.aspx

Comment: @PDB: need to clarify if want "only alphanumeric, any mixture of letters and numbers" or "only alphanumeric, has at least one letter and one number"

Comment: @pdb how many letters? How many numbers?

Comment: @pdb: updated my answer again.

Comment: @pdb -- do you care about non-alphanumerics?  I.e., if the field had a dollar-sign in it ($), would you want that to disqualify it?

Answer (score 10):

LIKE will do it. This is a double negative

```
where [field2] NOT LIKE '%[^0-9a-z]%'
```

It says:

- `%[^0-9a-z]%` means `not (alphanumeric)`
- `NOT LIKE '%[^0-9a-z]%'` means `not(not(alphanumeric))` -> alphanumeric

Edit:

For all numbers... "it works"

```
SELECT 'it works' WHERE '1234567' NOT LIKE '%[^0-9a-z]%'
```

All letters

```
SELECT 'it works' WHERE 'abcdefg' NOT LIKE '%[^0-9a-z]%'
```

Contains non-alphanumeric

```
SELECT 'it works' WHERE 'abc_123' NOT LIKE '%[^0-9a-z]%'
```

Edit 2:

This solution is for

> only alphanumeric, any mixture of letters and numbers

Edit 3:

<strike>letters followed by numbers</strike>

```
where [field2] NOT LIKE '%[^0-9a-z]%' AND [field2] LIKE '[a-z]%[0-9]'
```

Edit:

Finally, 2 letters and upto 3 numbers

```
where
   [field2] LIKE '[a-z][a-z][0-9]'
   OR
   [field2] LIKE '[a-z][a-z][0-9][0-9]'
   OR
   [field2] LIKE '[a-z][a-z][0-9][0-9][0-9]'
```

Comment: Then it will be fine - it fails the regular expression check (since there are no non-numbers, and then you inverse that with the NOT LIKE

Comment: @damien, hopefully OP is capable of copy/pasting an extra line

Comment: @Derek -- `...'9' LIKE '%[^0-9a-z]%'` fails?

Comment: @kuru kuru na... : I gave samples. See comment on question too to find out what OP **actually** means

Comment: Per your edit -- that was my point -- it works for '1234567'.  I think the OP wants it to fail in that case (because it doesn't contain letters AND numbers).

Comment: the set of data that needs to be selected usually start with a letter then end with a number.

Comment: @Derek -- OK?  OP said numbers AND letters.  The AND is the key word there.

Comment: @PDb: we can do that too with LIKE if you gave correct information. Edit your question to give **exact** pattern rules.

Comment: @kuru kuru na: OP just said it is letters followed by numbers

Comment: It's a great solution anyway as the question is currently worded. +1 :D

Comment: Edit3 matches `'a1b2'`, which isn't strictly letters followed by numbers.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever: true, was too hasty

Comment: what does `WHERE '1234567'` mean here? is `'1234567'` a column name? should you always do `WHERE` against a column name?

Comment: @Honey it's a string literal. a lomger vesions would be `DECLARE @foo varchar(100) = '1234567'; SELECT 'it works' WHERE @foo NOT LIKE '%[^0-9a-z]%'`

Answer (score 3):

If you need it to contain both numerics and letters, and no other characters, I think you have to use 3 like clauses. One `NOT LIKE`, as @gbn said, then 2 `LIKE`s to ensure both character classes are represented:

```
select * from (select '123' union all select 'abc' union all select 'a2') t(Field)
where Field LIKE '%[0-9]%' and Field like '%[a-z]%'
AND Field NOT LIKE '%[^0-9a-z]%'
```

returns one row, with `'a2'`.

---

If it should only be letters followed by numbers, I'm thinking you might be able to achieve this with a further not like, again inspired by @gbn:

```
NOT LIKE '%[0-9]%[a-z]%'
```

But it is starting to look like a regex in CLR might be the preferred route.

Answer (score 2):

What you would want to do is SQL-based regexp matching. Check this out: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163473.aspx

Quotes:

"Although T-SQL is extremely powerful for most data processing, it provides little support for text analysis or manipulation. Attempting to perform any sophisticated text analysis using the built-in string functions results in massively large functions and stored procedures that are difficult to debug and maintain."

And:

"However there's SQLCLR, a CLR user-defined function (UDF) that lets you create an efficient and less error-prone set of functions using the Microsoft® .NET Framework."

Then you get code examples. Isn't Microsoft great? :D

Comment: Why does everyone insist on rolling out CLR for simple LIKEs? Learn SQL: you don't need regex. Not all shops allow CLR anyway

Comment: @gbn, you have a point there, but CLR is much easier to read. Anyway, there is always the solution of LINQ-ing it all :D

Comment: Speak for yourself. I *love* SQL :-)

Answer (score 1):

I believe `PATINDEX` will do the trick for you. The query below checks for non 0-9 and non a-z characters, returning 0 if it doesn't find any (i.e., only #s and letters)

```
Select [field1], [field2] 
from [db1].[table1] 
where patindex('%[^0-9a-z]%', [field2]) = 0
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Select [field1], [field2] 

from [db1].[table1] 

where [field2] REGEXP '^[0-9a-fA-F]*$'
```

Comment: -1, nice idea chris, except for the fact that TSQL does not have regexp.

Comment: I may be wrong, but REGEXP is a MySQL keyword to the best of my knowledge, not a TSQL one. Equivalents in OracleSpeak : REGEXP_LIKE and DB2: LIKE. Thanks, standardization ;)

Comment: Ah, yes. Ignore me. Getting the two muddled. Sorry guys.