# Delete this virus by searching for matching strings

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have this screenshot of a virus:

[image]

```
<div style="display:none">women that cheat <a href="http://blog.armanda.com/page/women-who-cheat-with-married-men.aspx">go</a> online</div><div style="display:none">link <a href="http://by-expression.com/page/my-girlfriend-started-to-communicate-with-ex">online</a> how to cheat husband</div><div style="display:none">dating for married men <a href="http://by-expression.com/page/my-girlfriend-started-to-communicate-with-ex">click</a> why people cheat in relationships</div><div style="display:none">why do men have affairs <a href="http://by-expression.com/page/my-girlfriend-started-to-communicate-with-ex">women who cheated</a> when your husband cheats</div><div style="display:none">reasons why husband cheat <a href="http://blog.smartofficecloud.com/page/Reasons-Married-Men-Cheat">why wife cheat</a> i dream my husband cheated on me</div><div style="display:none">how to tell if wife has cheated <a href="http://www.cfrtu.org/events.asp">married men who cheat</a> my boyfriend cheated on me with my mom</div><div style="display:none">My girlfriend cheated on me <a href="http://www.chimneyfans.com/contents.aspx?page=Fans">link</a> women who cheat on husbands</div>
```

How can I find strings that start with `<div style="display:none">` and ends with `</div>` and delete it?

Comment: I've edited your question to fix some grammatical error and updated your title. Feel free to revert the edit if you need to.

Answer (score 1):

Wouldn't:

```
--To Check    
SELECT * 
FROM [YOUR_TABLE]
WHERE [YOUR_COLUMN] like '<div style="display:none">%'

--To delete
DELETE FROM [YOUR_TABLE]
WHERE [YOUR_COLUMN] like '<div style="display:none">%'
```

Work for you ?

### Edit

It sounds like you would need to use a Regular Expression in your Where clause:

[MSDN Article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174214.aspx)

[RegexPal to Test your regular Expression](http://regexpal.com/)

[Example of using Regex in Where Clause](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7204779/is-it-possible-to-use-the-where-clause-in-sql-to-only-show-a-field-containing)

Comment: no work i need search all tables and colums beginnig '<div style="display:none"> ending with "</div>"

regexp based sql search i need

sample regexp("^<div style="display:none">|</div>$" all tables and colums)

sample like this i need

Comment: @KuzeyCryptrOrgKaraeski Then you would need to look at regular expressions in your where clause https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174214.aspx

Comment: @KuzeyCryptrOrgKaraeski See the edit I made this should give you what you need to solve you problem.

Answer (score 0):

It solve your problem

```
UPDATE
lg 
SET lg.ACIKLAMA = REPLACE(lg.ACIKLAMA,t.cleaned,'')
 FROM log_GENELPARAMETRELER lg JOIN ( 


SELECT lg2.PARAMKOD , SUBSTRING(lg2.ACIKLAMA,(CHARINDEX('<div style="display:none">',lg2.ACIKLAMA)),(LEN(lg2.ACIKLAMA) - CHARINDEX('<div style="display:none">',lg2.ACIKLAMA) + 1)) AS cleaned

  FROM log_GENELPARAMETRELER lg2 WHERE lg2.ACIKLAMA LIKE '%<div style="display:none">%' ) t ON lg.PARAMKOD = t.PARAMKOD
```