# SQL LIKE and OR conditions,

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a column in the database's table with data format like this "000011" and an SQL query like:

```
SELECT *
FROM table
WHERE a = 000010 OR a = 000001 or a = 000011
```

But if the value is 111111. It will have a lot of OR condition in it. 
If data format like 001 (3 digits) it's can use wildcard ( _ )to do this, but I'm stuck when trying to use it in case (6 digits).

Please help me to find other ways?

Comment: Do you want to only see when a contains a 1?

Comment: a look like a value and not a string ( no quotes )

Comment: Are you wanting to create all of the combinations upto 111111in WHERE clause such as 000001, 000010, 000011, 000100, 000101 etc.. ?

Comment: Maybe this will help as well: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7204779/is-it-possible-to-use-the-where-clause-in-sql-to-only-show-a-field-containing

Comment: Can I ask why type of this field is not integer instead of string?

Comment: @NoorAShuvo Yes, something like that.

Matt Sorry maybe my question is not clear, I want to search exactly, something like NoorAShuvo mentioned

alirakiyan Another person design this table.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

First, you can use `in`:

```
SELECT *
FROM table
WHERE a in (000010, 000001, 000011)
```

But, I suspect your "data" is actually an integer and you want boolean & or |:

```
WHERE (a & 000011)
```

Comment: Hello, actually it's String, and each char is represented for 1 condition, 
Here is the demo
101 mean condition 1 true, condition 2 is false and condition 3 is true.
So need to search WHERE 
condition 1 true condition 2 false and 3  false (100)
condition 1 false condition 2 false and 3 true (001)
condition 1 true condition 2 false and 3 true (101)
Something like this.
Thanks.

Comment: @Nicky . . . It is not a string as you have asked your question.  Comparing strings to integers is not recommended.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to show data that contains a 1 then use `LIKE`

```
SELECT *
FROM table
WHERE a LIKE '%1%'
```

Comment: Hello, I'm sorry maybe my question is not clear. 
Assume that I have value like this 0111
It's will have an array like this
0001
0011
0111
0010 ...

So if using LIKE it's will contain 1000 and it's will get wrong data.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT *
FROM table
WHERE position('1' in a) > 0
```

Comment: Hello, sorry my question is not clear, with this value 111111
it will create an array value like this
000001
000011
000111 ...
And search with that array, not contain

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand you want to find all rows where the binary representation is less than your input. If that is the case, you could use the BINARY function to get the result you want:

```
mysql> create table bintab (a varchar(10));
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.07 sec)

mysql> insert into bintab values('000001');
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.04 sec)

mysql> insert into bintab values('000010');
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.01 sec)

mysql> insert into bintab values('000011');
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.01 sec)

mysql> insert into bintab values('000100');
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> insert into bintab values('000101');
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> insert into bintab values('000110');
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.01 sec)

mysql> insert into bintab values('000111');
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> select * from bintab where binary(a) < binary('000100');
+--------+
| a      |
+--------+
| 000001 |
| 000010 |
| 000011 |
+--------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```